# Specify build file for an example

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a build script that is unnecessary for the library but required to build some examples. How do I specify a build file for an example with Cargo? I tried the following:

```
[[example]]
name = "basic"
build = "examples/build.rs"
```

but Cargo tells me the `build` key is unused.

Comment: At that point, it doesn't really seem to fit with the concept of "just" an example to me. I'd encourage you to just split it out completely (perhaps using a workspace?). For my own curiosity, why does your example need a build script when your library doesn't?

Comment: The build script is to find the correct SDL2 DLL for Windows targets.

Comment: @Zack that sounds like a problem in setting up the correct path/environment. "Allow compiler/linker to find correct path to the SDL2 DLL" seems a more appropriate (and new) question to ask.